# Dump only part of sqlite database

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to dump only part of a database? I have a database containing 250'000 entries. I want to create a second one with a tenth of the data in it...

using

```
select * from table where id % 10 = 0
```

and setting

```
.output out.sql
```

yields a file that does not have the binary data encoded in the same way as when using

```
.dump

dump -> the binary data gets encoded as hex bytes
other way -> it gets encoded as some weird string
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of dumping to a file, you can directly write a new database:

```
ATTACH DATABASE New.db AS new;
CREATE TABLE new.stuff AS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id % 10 = 0);
```

This should create the table `stuff` in `New.db`.

Comment: I have got Error: near "(": syntax error
How to fix it?

Comment: @mrLSD Hi! Please post your code as a new question and someone will be able to help, I’m sure

Comment: Brackets in this answer are not needed for some queries, that's why @mrLSD sees this error. `CREATE TABLE new.stuff AS SELECT * FROM table;` is sufficient.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the `ATTACH` from terminal? I.e. by pipe?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the select offset and limit params if you know which range of rows you want.